# Payment error code: #00003

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, integration

I'm running into a problem while I am integrating PayPal into my Wordpress account. I've created sandbox account to try and run the payment. However, whenever I tried to ordered the item, it gives me this error:

**Fatal error: Payment error code: #00003 in /home/www/d-xchange.com/wp-content/themes/classiads-2-2/paypal/form-handler.php on line 133**

Does anyone has any experience in this before? As I'm not too sure whether the problem occurs in the integration or my sandbox account.

Hope to hear from you all soon.

Many thanks!

Comment: can u also include the line which gives error

Comment: PayPal errors usually come in either a Result Code or a 5-digit API error message, so it's not a PayPal error code.   There isn't a 00003 error message within PayPal.   So provide the code from the line in the error might help diagnoise the problem

Comment: Hi, the error code occur here:

if ( count($_POST) && (! isset($_POST['AMT']) || ! is_numeric($_POST['AMT']) || $_POST['AMT'] < 0) )
  trigger_error('Payment error code: #00003', E_USER_ERROR);